# Cache UIViewController for presentation/pushing

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, caching, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible/practical/beneficial to cache UIViewControllers at the startup of an app so that when they need to be presented (or pushed by a UINavigationController), the memory does not have to be allocated and they are already ready? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  You can do it in your application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

It's probably not particularly beneficial, though.  If these things take a while to load, you're forcing the user to endure a long wait at app launch time.  You're also loading view controllers before you even know if the user will need to see them.

Comment: Well in this case, I know that all three of my view controllers will be used, and they don't take particularly long to load: just under half a second. I would just rather have the user endure a launch time that is maybe two seconds longer than have an awkward pause after the button is pressed to move along to the new view. How exactly would I cache a view controller in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: so that it was accessible throughout the app?

Comment: Add properties to your app delegate to hold the view controllers.  Initialize the properties in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to your view controllers (which you allocate and initialize in that method).  Use the property values when you need the view controllers.

Comment: Awesome- no more awkward pause! =) Thanks!